# Strange hum when I touch a wire inside pickup cavity

Tags: guitar, pick-ups

I am trying to diagnose some shoddy wiring of some active pickups. All the wiring is done and appears to work. However I get:

- some buzz from neck pickup when a note is played. Bridge pickup is fine
- weird hum when touching wire to selector switch from bridge volume pot (see video)

Comment: Hum when touching components is a grounding issue, which means something is not connected correctly. Check all the soldering, and switches and pots. We have a number of posts on here about grounding so please have a read

Comment: The hum when poking things is because your body acts a big antenna, picking up mains frequency hum from all the wiring around you.  Don't poke things, and it won't hum.

Comment: Right I understand that concept - but an insulated wire is conducting that electricity? That's what i don't get